# Error when trying to run a .py file from command prompt

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python 3.7.3, when I try to run a saved .py file this happens

```
C:\Users\olive>cd desktop

C:\Users\olive\Desktop>hello.py
 File "C:\Users\olive\Desktop\hello.py", line 1
   Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone know how to fix this,
thanks

Comment: Why on Earth does your file contain _literally_ "Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32"?! And how did it even get there? Please show the contents of `hello.py`

Comment: @ForceBru My bet is on a modified version of `print sys.version` and there is a version check inside the .py file where both side of the if-statement do not match in a try/except-loop resulting in a SyntaxError thrown back at OP. Probably matter of incorrect string manipulation prior to comparison of sides. Ohole.. post script part please.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
python3 hello.py
```

I think will be running